# How to iterate columns with control statement?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code right now:

```
import pandas as pd


df_area=pd.DataFrame({"area":["Coesfeld","Recklinghausen"],"factor":[2,5]})
df_timeseries=pd.DataFrame({"Coesfeld":[1000,2000,3000,4000],"Recklinghausen":[2000,5000,6000,7000]})

columns_in_timeseries=list(df_timeseries)
columns_to_iterate=columns_in_timeseries[0:]

newlist=[]

for i,k in enumerate(columns_to_iterate):
    new=df_area.loc[i,"factor"]*df_timeseries[k]
    newlist.append(new)

newframe=pd.DataFrame(newlist)
df1_transposed = newframe.T
```

The code multiplys each factor from an area with the timeseries from that area. In this example the code is iterating immediately the rows and columns after multiplying. In the next step I want to expand the `df_area`-Dataframe like the following:

```
df_area=pd.DataFrame({"area":["Coesfeld","Coesfeld","Recklinghausen","Recklinghausen"],"factor":[2,3,5,6]})
```

As you can see, I have different factors for the same area. The goal is to iterate the columns in `df_timeseries` only when the area in `df_area` changes. My first intention is to use an if-Statement but right now I have no idea how to realize that with the for-loop.

Comment: Which factor should be used for `Coesfeld` and `Recklinghausen` in your expanded example, then? 2 and 5 (i.e. the first factor for the new area) or 3 and 6 (i.e. the last factor before the area changes)?

Comment: Both factors should be used. That means that I need an output for `Coesfeld` with the factor 2 and one output with the factor 3. After that it should go on with `Recklinghausen` using the factor 5 and 6. So the factors are in the same count like the area.

Comment: Just to make sure: So that means that for `Coesfeld` the result should be a Series with values `6000`, `12000`, `18000`, `24000` (i.e. the initial values times 2 times 3)? And do you always have the same number of factors for the areas, or could there be cases where there are e.g. two factors for `Coesfeld` and three for `Recklinghausen`?

Comment: No its not always the same number of factors for the areas, its completely varying. So its possible that there are three factors for the Recklinghausen, and e.g. six for coesfeld.

Comment: The first series for `Coesfeld`should be: 2000,4000,6000,8000. The second series for Coesfeld should be: 3000;6000,9000,12000. So for `Coesfeld`the factors `2`and `3`were used. The next step than would be `Recklinghausen`with the factors `5`and `6`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't shake off the suspicion that there is something wrong about your whole approach. A first red flag is your use of [wide format instead of long format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_and_narrow_data) – in my experience, that's probably going to cause you unnecessary trouble.

Be it as it may, here's a function that takes a data frame with time series data and a second data frame with multiplier values and area names as arguments. The two data frames use the same structure as your examples `df_timeseries` (area names as columns, time series values as cell values) and `df_area` (area name as values in column `area`, multiplier as value in column `factor`). I'm pretty sure that this is not a good way to organize your data, but that's up to you to decide.

What the function does is it iterates through the rows of the second data frame (the `df_area`-like). It uses the `area` value to select the correct series from the first data frame (the `df_timeseries`-like), and multiplies this series with the `factor` value from that row. The result is added as an element within a list generator.

```
def do_magic(df1, df2):
    return [df1[area] * factor for area, factor in zip(df2.area, df2.factor)]
```

You can insert this directly into your code to replace your loop:

```
df_area = pd.DataFrame({"area": ["Coesfeld", "Recklinghausen"],
                        "factor": [2, 5]})
df_timeseries = pd.DataFrame({"Coesfeld": [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000],
                              "Recklinghausen": [2000, 5000, 6000, 7000]})

newlist = do_magic(df_timeseries, df_area)
newframe = pd.DataFrame(newlist)    
df1_transposed = newframe.T
```

It also works with your expanded `df_area`. The resulting list will consist of four series (two for `Coesfeld`, two for `Recklinghausen`).